# Is the "decapsulate" function from lattice based cryptography homomorphic?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, lattice-crypto, kyber

Observing the code example from [pqcrypto-kyber](https://docs.rs/pqcrypto-kyber/0.6.4/pqcrypto_kyber/kyber1024/index.html), is the decapsulate function $d$ homomorphic?

If $d(ct, sk_i) = ss_i$, is it true that $d(ct, \sum_i sk_i) = \sum_i ss_i$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Kyber claims to be CCA secure. CCA schemes cannot be homomorphic (thinking through this may be a useful exercise).

It may be useful to try to work through this particular example with pen and paper by looking at algorithm 5 in the [Kyber paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/634.pdf). Note that what is returned is some hash, which you should not expect to have homomorphic properties.